# Como fazer uma busca com Join usando Entity framework Lambda e Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Como eu faria pra fazer uma busca em duas ou mais tabelas.

No sistema que estou fazendo, eu tenho as tabelas Barco, TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco e ClasseBarco

Meu mapeamento ta da seguinte forma:

```
       HasRequired(c => c.ClasseBarco)
            .WithMany(c => c.Barcos)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ClasseBarcoId);

       HasRequired(c => c.TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco)
            .WithMany(c => c.Barcos)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.TipoOperacaoId);
```

Fiz um respositorio genérico para fazer buscas

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Buscar(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Dbset.Where(predicate);
    }
```

E eu uso esse repositorio genérico para fazer as buscas especificas da classe barcos, segue alguns exemplo abaixo:

```
    public IEnumerable<Barco> ObterAtivos()
    {
        return Buscar(c => c.Ativo && !c.Excluido);          
    }

    public Barco ObterPorNome(string nome)
    {
        return Buscar(c => c.Nome == nome).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

E se eu quiser buscar o TipoDeOperacaoDoBarcoe e a ClasseBarco, que são tabelas diferentes, mas que estão relacionadas com tabela barco, como eu faria?

Minha ideia é mostrar esses dados em uma tabela

Segue abaixo como está meu banco

[image: Dados banco]

Comment: Buscar a partir de Barco ?

Comment: @FelippeTadeu isso, vamos supor que eu quero saber qual a Classe e o Tipo de barco de um determinado barco

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Para realizar a busca conforme o comentário colocado, a busca seria da seguinte forma:

```
public Tipo BuscarPorBarco(int idBarco){
    return Buscar(t => t.Barco.IdBarco == idBarco).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Essa resposta é dada pensando que em sua classe `Tipo` existe uma propriedade para relacionamento entre `Tipo` e `Barco`, sendo ela por exemplo:

```
public virtual ICollection<Barco> Barco { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Para buscar dados em duas ou mais tabelas relacionadas, você pode usar a sintaxe de "join" no Entity Framework com as expressões lambda e Linq. No seu caso, para buscar o TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco e a ClasseBarco, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
public IEnumerable<Barco> ObterPorTipoOperacaoEClasse(string tipoOperacao, string classeBarco)
{
    return Buscar(b => b.TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco.Descricao == tipoOperacao && b.ClasseBarco.Descricao == classeBarco);
}
```

Neste exemplo, estamos buscando todos os barcos que têm um TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco com uma determinada descrição e uma ClasseBarco com uma determinada descrição. A expressão lambda b => refere-se à tabela de Barco, enquanto b.TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco.Descricao e b.ClasseBarco.Descricao são as propriedades relacionadas das outras tabelas.

Você também pode usar a sintaxe de "join" explicitamente no seu método de busca, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public IEnumerable<Barco> ObterPorTipoOperacaoEClasse(string tipoOperacao, string classeBarco)
{
    return Dbset
        .Join(context.TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco, b => b.TipoOperacaoId, t => t.Id, (b, t) => new { Barco = b, TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco = t })
        .Join(context.ClasseBarco, bt => bt.Barco.ClasseBarcoId, c => c.Id, (bt, c) => new { bt.Barco, bt.TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco, ClasseBarco = c })
        .Where(x => x.TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco.Descricao == tipoOperacao && x.ClasseBarco.Descricao == classeBarco)
        .Select(x => x.Barco);
}
```

Neste exemplo, estou usando a sintaxe de "join" para juntar as três tabelas e selecionar apenas os Barcos que correspondem aos critérios de TipoDeOperacaoDoBarco e ClasseBarco especificados. Observe que o código se torna mais complexo do que o exemplo anterior e pode ser mais difícil de ler e manter.